# Почему присваиваемое значение выражает свойство <length>?

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr3 = ["a", "b", "c"];
arr3 = arr3.push("d", "e"); // Почему показывает число?//
console.log(arr3); // Ожидал a, b, c, d, e //
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp - смотрите "Return Value"

Comment: Я понимаю, как это работает, если просто arr3.push("d", "e");. Но почему при  arr3 = arr3.push("d", "e") возвращает 5? (length).

Comment: Потому что новая длина массива `arr3` - `5`.

Comment: Igor, а почему он таким образом показывает длину? Этому есть объяснение?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

> **Return Value:** A Number, representing the new length of the array
>
> **Возвращает:** Число, представляющее новую длину массива.

```js
var arr3 = ["a", "b", "c"];

var newLength = arr3.push("d", "e"); 
console.log(newLength);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr3));

newLength = arr3.push("f"); 
console.log(newLength);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr3));
```

Comment: После добавления элементов обновляется свойство длины, что и возвращается?

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan Тоже хороший перевод :).

Comment: Ok Igor, уже разобрался, спасибо. :)